# Pyside: detecting single and double clicks on a QWidget

Tags: python, user-interface, mouseevent, pyside

I am building a UI in Maya that when a button is clicked will generate a bunch of horizontal layouts containing widgets inside of a `QScrollArea`.  I am trying to figure out how to get each row to recognize a single / double click.  When a particular row is clicked, I would like it to return the widget that was clicked so that I can do something with it. I am thinking I will probably have to attach a container widget to the row layouts to recognize the mouse clicks?

I have figured out how in general to recognize single and double clicks and have it print something - but I am having a hard time figuring out how to link that to a widget.

Answer (score 7):

Below is a demo that should do most of what you want. The key method is [childAt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#childAt-4), which gets the child widget at a given point. Obviously, for this to work, all of the target widgets must be descendants of the widget that handles the events. The `lastpos` check is used to detect a true click-event (i.e. a mouse-press and -release on the same widget).

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.scroll)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        for text in 'red green yellow purple orange blue'.split():
            item = QtGui.QFrame()
            item.setObjectName(text)
            item.setStyleSheet('background-color: %s' % text)
            layout.addWidget(item)
        self.scroll.setWidget(widget)
        self._lastpos = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self._lastpos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        widget = self.childAt(event.pos())
        if (widget is not None and self._lastpos is not None and
            widget is self.childAt(self._lastpos)):
            if widget.objectName():
                print('click:', widget.objectName())
        self._lastpos = None

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        widget = self.childAt(event.pos())
        if widget is not None and widget.objectName():
            print('dblclick:', widget.objectName())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 300, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Yes!! implemented your examples and it worked!  So for all of my generated widgets in my scrollarea, i store them in a dictionary, and I was able to call that widget again and edit it (like changing the background color) by just using self.mywidget[widget.objectName()].  Is there a better way to edit a widget with the objectName or is that a good way to do that?

Comment: @ghost654. It sounds perfectly reasonable to use a dictionary. Then again, since you already have the widget, I suppose you could also emit a custom `rowClicked` signal that sent the widget that was clicked, then set the background in a connected slot.

Comment: Is there a way to specify to only accept the mousePressEvent, mouseReleaseEvent, and MouseDoubleClickEvent from the left click button?  looks like right click is doing the same thing.

Is there an event i can use that will look for right clicks also?  To do a dropdown menu

Comment: nevermind about the right click, I found this looks for right click -
def contextMenuEvent(self, event):